# Is it possible populate the updated data in a repeater with out refreshing the page/using and update panel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

H All,
Is it possible to populate the updated data from the database to a repeater with out refreshing the page and with out using an update panel?

This is my requirement.

I have an option to save Name & Age to the database 
eg:

Name <*textbox accepts name> : Age <*textbox accepts the name> **Save Button**

i have a repeater which displays first 50 items displayed below save panel.
eg:

**Name                  Age**
Rahul                  30
Sameera                32
Manju                  28

On click of the Save button I am calling Jquery to insert my data into the database. After this i need to update my repeater as well.

I don't wanna refresh the page or to use update panel.
Is there any option to do so???using some jquery or some thing like that????

Answer (score 1):

1-use JQuery to call PageMethods or a webservice
2-grab the results
3-update the repeater area

this function calls a webservice and grabs back a list of items in json format:

```
function LoadLatestLocations(ParentPage) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Admission/AdmissionService.asmx/LoadLocations",
        data: "{'ParentPage':'" + ParentPage + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //write the code to create the repeater structure in html from data.d
            var str = '<table>.....</table>';
            $('.repeaterDiv').html(str);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if i use jquery, how can i do this? Could you please update some links??

Comment: 3- how to update the repeater area without using update panel?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. if you don't want to bother with serverside and json and xml and restful api and etc, just use this code. It correspond to ["Unobtrusive JavaScript"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) principle, so your page will work also without JavaScript. And it doesn't require any changes at serverside.

HTML body:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="new-person" action="./create-new-person.html" method="POST">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></label>
    <label>Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age" /></label>
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" />
  </form>

  <div class="persons">
    <p class="person"><span class="name">Darth</span>, <span class="age">60</span></p>
    <p class="person"><span class="name">Luk</span>, <span class="age">25</span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden-container" style="display: none;"/>
```

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#save').click(function(e){
    var url = $('#new-person').attr('action');
    var outgoingData = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        age: $('#age').val()
    };
    var showPersons = function(data) {
      $('#hidden-container').html(data);
      $('#wrapper .persons').html($('#hidden-container .persons').html());
      $('#hidden-container').empty();
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: outgoingData,
      success: showPersons,
      context: document.body
    });    

    // prevent really submitting a form
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Of course, action page may be the same as current.

Comment: Thanks. On success, how can i get the datas from the database?